# Firebase cloud function returns null to client even though it succeeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been try to write my first cloud function, which you can see below. In the cloud function log, it outputs that it hits the first `console.log(Successful: userRecord.uid)` but doesn't seem to do anything after it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to what is wrong?

Thank you very much.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
admin.initializeApp();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, res) =>
{
    console.time();
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: true,
        password: data.password,
        disabled: false
    })
        .then(userRecord => {
            console.log('Successful: ', userRecord.uid);
            const message = {
                firstname: data.firstname,
                lastname: data.lastname
            }
            return db.collection('Users').add(message)
                .then(() => {
                    return "Success";
                })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
            console.trace();
            console.timeEnd();
            return "Error";
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone wondering, I was able to fix my own issue:

For me, I needed to return each function, so the code became this:

Notice the `return` on `admin.auth().createUser`

````
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
admin.initializeApp();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, res) =>
{
    console.time();
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: true,
        password: data.password,
        disabled: false
    })
        .then(userRecord => {
            console.log('Successful: ', userRecord.uid);
            const message = {
                firstname: data.firstname,
                lastname: data.lastname
            }
            return db.collection('Users').add(message)
                .then(() => {
                    return "Success";
                })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
            console.trace();
            console.timeEnd();
            return "Error";
        });
});```
````

Comment: Specifically, as the documentation states, you're supposed to return a promise that resolves with the data you want to send to the client.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't do it correctly, would you be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks!